# Types of light-matter interaction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, atomic-physics

I'm going to study the photoionization, that is the emission of an atom's electron because of it's interaction with EM radiation.

To contextualize it, I would like to know what other effects can the light-matter interaction lead.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production - There's a nice table on the side.

Comment: This question lacks focus. Whole books ("Photons and Atoms", Cohen-Tannoudji) were written on this subject.

Comment: See table 1 on this Lecture Note on Photon interactions and Cross Sections by H.Hirayama rcwww.kek.jp/research/shield/photon_r.pdf for photon-matter interactions. On the other hand, wave-matter interactions like reflection, refraction, interference, and diffraction are explained by Huygens-Fresnel principle. Reflection can also be analogized with the elastic collision of the photons off a surface. Scattering, to keep things simple, is just reflection of light off the curved surface of a small particle.

Answer (score 2):

without being exhaustive, here are a few examples:

- **Reflexion on a metallic surface**: interaction between the free electrons of the metallic body and the incident light wave. Basis of the part of optics dealing with mirrors.
- **Bragg diffraction**: interaction of a light wave with the electrons of atoms regularly spaced in a cristalline lattice. Used to study cristalline structures.
- **Other cristalline lattice / light interactions**: LEDs (diodes), LASER diodes, .
- **Refraction**:  Interaction of light with an amorphous transparent body (glass, water, air) where light rays change course due a change in index (light velocity in a given body). This is the basis of the part of optics dealing with lenses.
- **Excitation of atomic or molecular energy states** (transitions between levels of energy): Basis for the Laser. Also the mechanism behind fluorescence phenomena, phosphorescence.
- **Black Body radiation** : Light (distribution) emitted by a body at a given temperature: example: A light bulb or a star or an oven.